# specify Index hint in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I need to specify a Index hint for my HQL

```
  Query.setComment()
```

method is of no use as it is appending the hint before the select clause, 
  though this can be achieved by NativeSQL but  I just wanted to check is there a way we can achieve this in HQL rather then SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per My understanding there is no support for specifying index hints in HQL currently as of version 3.6.5

though this can be achieved by specifying @NamedNativeQueries  or by calling CreateSQLQuery() on query interface

Answer (score 0):

You can find a technique I use to specify [Query Hints here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/23/use-sql-server-query-hints-with-nhibernate-hql-and-icriteria/), you can adapt this to insert some custom SQL inside some specific HQL or ICriteria query.

In my example I'm only interested in adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) or OPTION (HASH JOIN) but the technique comments<->interceptor can be used to manipulate the generate SQL in any way.